# JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

i'm trying to post some data to the data base using django rest framework this is the user profile so the user must be able to add this informations to his profile but im getting this error when i do a post request with some dummy data:

"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 14 (char 86)"

her is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)
    wilaya = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)
    store_coordinates = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)
    documents1 = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)
    documents2 = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

serializer.py

```
class ProfileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user_id')
```

the view.py

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        account = Account.objects.filter(username=user)
        serializer = AccountSerializer(account, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save(commit=False)
            instance.user_id = request.user
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

dummy data

```
{"first_name":"jhone",
"last_name":"mike",
"wilaya":"jijel",
"city":"18";
"address": "MyAdress",
"store_coordinates":"87689787",
"documents1":"image",
"documents2":"docx",}
```

Comment: Your dummy data is not valid json. Change `;` to `,` and remove the last `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the json data, change the line `"city":"18";` to `"city":"18",`, the separator for JSON data is `,` and not `;` :

```
{"first_name":"jhone",
"last_name":"mike",
"wilaya":"jijel",
"city":"18",
"address": "MyAdress",
"store_coordinates":"87689787",
"documents1":"image",
"documents2":"docx",}
```